# Sort arraylist in android date and others string

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

**I have an arraylist with the following string.**

> Tuesday, Thursday, Monday, Saturday.

And I want to appear sorted like:

> Monday, Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday.

It is possible that appears Sunday,  Wednesday..

**And I have an arraylist with the following String.**

> dog, rabbit, cow, duck, cat.

And I want to appear sorted like:

> rabbit, cat, cow, duck, dog.

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should make a `Comparator` for each. [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
public final class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b)
    {
        //Return +1 if a>b, -1 if a<b, 0 if equal
    }
}
```

For your days of the week you might want to make your comparator similar to this;

```
public final class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    private String[] items ={
        "monday",
        "tuesday",
        "wednesday",
        "thursday",
        "friday",
        "saturday",
        "sunday"
    };
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b)
    {
        int ai = items.length, bi=items.length;
        for(int i = 0; i<items.length; i++)
        {
            if(items[i].equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                ai=i;
            if(items[i].equalsIgnoreCase(b))
                bi=i;
        }
        return ai-bi;
    }
}
```

Then to sort your arraylist according to your custom order;

```
MyComparator myComparator = new MyComparator();
Collections.sort(myArrayList, myComparator);
```

You can call `Collections.sort()` without the 2nd parameter if you need the default ordering of the type (If it implements comparable). [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: You define the comparison whether `a` is less than `b`, inside the `compare` method. I've provided an example of one of the possible implementations to do this.

Comment: Updated, now the answer should make more sense to @JuanA.Doval

Comment: Yeah, i removed the additional comment part, easy mistakes when writing code without compiling/running. Thanks

Comment: Ahh, but the comment was funny doe.

Comment: dont work :(, list is not sorted., i put a.toLowerCase(), eclipse make a error with toLower

Comment: @MohammadS. The site isn't about being funny though, 3 other people rejected it before I even saw it.

Comment: @JuanA.Doval I assure you `Collections.sort()` works, either the comparator is not sorting the items correctly, your items aren't what you think they are or your not calling `Collections.sort()`

Comment: @JuanA.Doval Your title says sorting of android date? If your formatting strings from date objects, you would be best to sort the list of dates using default comparator. And then produce the strings from the sorted list.

Comment: is not real date, only is name of day., i will try whit log. to see results.

Comment: http://ideone.com/WESbHG It works for me, perhaps you need to include trim or use contains rather than equals.

Comment: in one arraylist, "list of animals" work, but de daylist dont work.. the list is in spanish, and wednesday is miércoles, the problem can be 'é' in mi"é"rcoles?

Comment: Finally works all fine, i dont know because don't work first time, give points and i can put points, because now i have only 13 points and i cant valorate.. thanks.!

Comment: @JuanA.Doval It's quite possible that accent's cause the equality to screwup, would have to find a different equality check if that turns out to be true.
I don't understand your word valorate.

Comment: sorry, is not valorate is i cant rate. :D